# UWP XAML designer exception - Template10 stopped working suddenly

Tags: xaml, uwp, behavior, template10

From one moment to another I am receiving the following error messages:
When starting the UWP app:
One of the content dialog constructor -> InitializeComponent() throws the following exception:

Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: 'The text associated with this error code could not be found.
Cannot deserialize XBF metadata property list as 'Behaviors' was not found in type 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.Interaction'. [Line: 0 Position: 0]'

http://prntscr.com/rb8bdj

And I can't open the XAML Designer:
http://prntscr.com/rb8boo

Template10 version: 1.1.12
Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed: 2.0.1
So the latest.

There was no any previous sign, this error come up from one moment to another today, everything was working smoothly before.

Can you please suggest anything how can I fix it or debug it?

Solution:
Finally figured out that anything went wrong with the project configuration, after deleting and readding the debug config solved the problem.

Comment: Hi, Have you installed the package: `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed`, if not, please install it via nuget package manager.

Comment: Yes, I installed it.
http://prntscr.com/rb9aa7

Comment: Hi, can you provide a minimum runnable demo so that we can reproduce your problem? Mainly want to know how you build `ContentDialog`.

Comment: I am not going to share the whole code, it's not relating with the dialog.
Anything is going wrong with the template10 in debug mode.
I created a test repo: https://github.com/Satukan/App1 
A grid with a textbox using template 10. I have an issue, although it's different. The textbox shows, but fails at run. http://prntscr.com/rbign2

Comment: This is strange, I can't reproduce your problem. I downloaded the example you provided, but it worked well. What is your development environment? For example, the version of Windows 10 and the version of Visual Studio. The environments I used for testing were Windows 10-1809 and Visual Studio 2019. You can also try to delete the `bin` and `obj` folders inside the project and then rebuild the project

Comment: Thank you for checking it. I am using from everything the latest stable, including Visual Studio 2019, nuget packages etc.. The target versions are 1809 / 1903.
Also tried to delete all of the bin/obj, the vs folder without success. 
Finally I figured out that it is relating with the configuration (I am using 3 - Debug/Local, Debug/Azure, Release) and the development Debug/Local caused the problem (I have no clue what happened). I deleted and readded simply and now it is working again. Fingers crossed that it stays like this.

Comment: Glad you found the solution, you can share your solution process as the answer, this can help more people